# Taking an array of full names and sorting it by surname

Tags: jquery, arrays, sorting

I want to sort an array of full names alphabetically by last name using JQuery or JavaScript but keep getting lost in loops and splits. Can anyone help?

```
var names = ["Adam Benson", "Clare Donaldson", "Ben Adams", "Donald Clarkson"];
```

Thanks and sorry for what seems like a very simple question!

Comment: Run. Run far, far away. Names are always more complicated than they appear. Is it possible you'll have "Adam James Benson" (e.g., a middle name) or "Adam Demby Benson" (e.g., two last names) or "Adam Charles Copernicus Smith Benson" (e.g., who knows)? If you definitely have only two names and it's definitely the second one you want, there are answers below to address that. Just be wary of real-world name data.

Comment: Pablo Diego José Francisco de Paula Juan Nepomuceno María de los Remedios Cipriano de la Santísima Trinidad Ruiz y Picasso, better known as Pablo Picasso

Comment: @VoteyDisciple Yeah, I do wish the data I was using had "first-name", "last-name" but what can you do? Just for a small exercise so hopefully it won't become a problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it with help of **[`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)**, **[`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)** and **[`String#localeComapre`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)** methods.

```js
var names = ["Adam Benson", "Clare Donaldson", "Ben Adams", "Donald Clarkson"];

// sort  array with custom functions
names.sort(function(a, b) {
  // compare lastname part for sorting
  return a.split(' ')[1].localeCompare(b.split(' ')[1]);
})

console.log(names);
```

**FYI :** In case name contains middle name part then  change `name.split(' ')[1]` to `name.split(' ').pop()` to get the last element from array(which is thw lastname).

Comment: Perfect, thank you! (For this and for drawing my attention to localeCompare)

Comment: @GilesTaylor : glad to help you :)

Comment: But would failed e.g on `Alberto De Sousa`

Comment: @A.Wolff : check `FYI` part

Comment: Ya, but it would return `Sousa` instead of `De Sousa`. All that to say, there is absolutely no way to retreive family name just by splitting full name

Comment: @A.Wolff :  for that `name.split(' ').slice(1).join(' ')` , I don't think that he needs to sort such complex names ;)

Comment: @A.Wolff :  `name.slice(name.indexOf(' ') + 1)` ,  `name.substr(name.indexOf(' ') + 1)` or  `name.substring(name.indexOf(' ') + 1)`

Comment: @PranavCBalan That's just specific to this example. There is many other examples where it will still fail.

Comment: @A.Wolff : the basic idea was given ...... other things depends on his need..... I think he is capable of doing the rest of things..... :)

Comment: @A. Wolff - apparently you don't use prefixes such as "de", "van", "von" etc., when alphabetizing surnames (although I did just jump on the first website telling me that for convenience).

Comment: And thank you @PranavCBalan -you've given me plenty to work with!

Comment: @GilesTaylor Thx for the info

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with a `sort()` function that splits the values by space and compares the last values of the resulting array:

```js
var names = ["Adam Benson", "Clare Donaldson", "Ben Adams", "Donald Clarkson"]; 
names.sort(function(a, b) {
    var aSurname = a.split(' ').pop();
    var bSurname = b.split(' ').pop();
    return aSurname < bSurname ? -1 : aSurname > bSurname ? 1 : 0;
})

console.log(names);
```

You would possibly also need to add some validation to this code in the case where there are no spaces in the provided name.

Comment: Thanks for this! This is just for a small exercise I'm doing but thanks for the heads up about validation.